# textbox - btn and label

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox

I have the next code and i don't get why it's not working.

```
  <asp:Label ID="lblFull" Visible="false" runat="server">

  <asp:TextBox ID="EmailtxtboxFull" Width="250px"  runat="server" Font-Size="Medium" ForeColor="Blue" BorderWidth="1"></asp:TextBox>

 </asp:Label>


  <asp:Label ID="lblEnd"  Visible="false" runat="server"></asp:Label>

 <asp:Button ID="btnFull" OnClick="btnFull_Click" runat="server" Text="Send" Font-Size="Medium" ForeColor="#0066FF" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1" />
```

c # code :

```
protected void btnFull_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        String Email = EmailtxtboxFull.Text.ToString();
        lblFull.Visible = false;
        lblEnd.Visible = true;
        lblEnd.Text = Email;
}
```

When i click on the btn ... i got empty lable and not the email that i wrote on the textbox. why this it's happent? that's connect to the autopostback ? how to fix that?

Comment: Do you have any code in the Page_Load event?

Comment: Try moving EmailtxtboxFull outside the label tags

Comment: Why is your textbox inside of your label tags?

Comment: But i need that... the start code of the aspx page includ more code... i have lable "choose type: short or full" ... if click on full so.. the user get that EmailtxtboxFull

Comment: Ok i know what to do.. i'll listen to you. i'll delete those lables and i'll do the txtbox visble = false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your EmailtxtboxFull textbox inside your label, are you sure the code sample is right?

when i corrected the label the code behaved correctly for me.